# Python DictWriter not writing certain rows in multi-client application

Tags: python, csv

I've got a client-server python program in the works, currently I'm running it with 2 clients sending data to the server. When I run it I start one client and then the other a few seconds later.

The issue is that when I look at the database after the clients have finished, I only see the entries written for the second client (the one that was started last), even though the program output (stdout) shows it going past the section of code that writes to the csv for the data coming from both clients. Both clients send information over at 10 second intervals. Below is the code where the server takes a message in. It writes to the csv file in question in the case where strs[0] == '\'cpu':

```
def serverLoop(conn):
with open(database, 'wb') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['cpu', 'pid', 'memory']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames, 
        quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    writer.writeheader()
    while 1:
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        #print 'data is', repr(data)
        #if repr(data) == COMPLETE: break
        conn.send(data)

        strs = repr(data).split()
        if strs[0] == '\'Thread':
            t = strs[9]
            process = strs[4] 
            logging.info('Heartbeat from thread with pid %s running at %s seconds' % (process, t))

        if strs[0] == '\'cpu':
            cpuData = strs[1] + ', ' + strs[2]
            print 'cpu data received'
            writer.writerow({'cpu': cpuData})
            print cpuData
            print 'wrote to db'
```

I'm using python 2.7 on ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

A csv file is not a database. If you write to a file from two different programs at the same time, only the last save will 'win' (overwriting the other one).

Comment: Sorry, maybe I should have clarified, only the function you see above is writing to that CSV, it is just receiving data from 2 different clients.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably how you are opening the file. Using mode `"wb"` will truncate the file each time you open it, throwing away any previous contents it had. If each of your clients connects to the server once, this is probably why you're seeing only the second one.

Try using mode `"ab"` instead of `"wb"`. The `"a"` stands for "append" mode, which allows writing and automatically seeks to the end of the file.

A downside to this is that if you use your current code you'll get duplicate headers, since you're writing them each time you set up a `DictReader`. You might want to do some extra checking to see if the file already has some content, and only write the header if it did not. An easy way to do this is to call `csvfile.tell()`, which reports your position in the file. Since append mode seeks to the end of the file, it will be zero only if the file is empty (or didn't previously exist).